# Re-close this question as a dupe instead of off-topic?

Tags: discussion

**TLDR**: Suggest reclosing a question as a duplicate to make its valuable answers easier to find.

---

The question [Comparing object properties in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp) (1) was closed as off-topic. In itself I agree with that; but what is unfortunate is that it has a number of good answers that (IMO) *more effectively* cover some of the same ground in as other similar questions.

If the question were written in a way that fit the site requirements better, it probably would have taken  the place of [Finding property differences between two C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387946/finding-property-differences-between-two-c-sharp-objects) (2). In fact if it had been asked more recently (I could imagine) with some editing it might have been left open anyway.

This second question has useful information but doesn't seem to be as well-developed overall as the first; and in at least one case answers here are just linking to answers there.

Is it possible and/or reasonable to re-close the first question as a duplicate of the second? This would meet core intent of the OP in question #1, and also this would make for much more useful content overall. It would direct readers to the 'right' place more quickly. Definitely would have saved me some time just now. (Enough time that it seemed worthwhile to take even more time to write this out! :)

Comment: Seems like it should be dupe-closed; but I'll take into consideration any arguments made for or against in the answers.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I suppose another possibility would be to edit #1 to actually make it read more like an explicit duplicate. But I'm not sure if that is better overall, and its certainly more work.

Comment: There's still the option of merging the two questions to keep all answers in the same place, both being nearly a decade old it may take some work from a SME to merge them properly that said

Comment: @George Stocker: It needs some copy editing, but it is locked.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree, it should remain with historical lock.

This is an ancient post from a time when SO had different quality standards. It is clearly not a good question by today's standards: it is too broad and asking for opinions. (Would have been ok on the Code Review site though.)

Duplicate is kind of the "last" close option to consider - it is normally used for questions that have been asked before, but are otherwise ok. But this question is not ok, regardless of dupes.

Historical lock is the perfect option for posts that don't live up to the site's current standards, yet holds value worth preserving.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... but keeping the historical lock and closing it for a different reason (duplicate vs. off-topic) don't seem to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: @DaveInCaz What exactly would be the point with that?

Comment: The point of re-closing it is to make it easier to find. The current valid question on this topic doesn't have as good answers as this one (IMO)

Comment: @DaveInCaz If that's the case then maybe a merge would be the best way to go. You could try to band together a bunch C# gurus here on meta and make a proposal of how to best merge without causing information loss. Then a mod can carry out the merge.